# How can I communicate from my Windows desktop with a USB connected Printer, that uses ZPL/Zebra programming language. Can I send commands using CMD?

Tags: serial-port, barcode, zpl, printers

I have a Brady BB12 Printer, that is connected to my Windows 10 Desktop using USB.

I am trying to communicate with this Printer and send it basic print commands. I know this printer recognizes ZPL/Zebra programming language. I am trying to use CMD or any other text editor to send commands to it. I'm sure I have to specify the port names and printer details correct?

However, after going through the documentation I can't seem to find clear commands, that allow me to communicate with this printer and send it basic print commands.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: From what I can see, without actually owning a Brady BB12 Printer, is that you [first install the driver](https://www.bradyid.com/downloads?filename=BBP12_Printer_Driver.exe), then [download the manual](https://d37iyw84027v1q.cloudfront.net/Common/BBP12_User_Manual_EN.pdf) and find the command tool. That could work. However, after you installed the Windows driver, you can [use it like any other printer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/print).